# How to rename multiple without randomizing the order of the files

Tags: python

I am trying to rename like 1k+ images however I want to keep their order.

Currently what I am doing works but randomizes the order of the images

```
# Python program to rename all file
# names in your directory
import os

os.chdir('Box Images - Renamed')
print(os.getcwd())

for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_name = "" + str(count)

    new_name = f'{f_name}{f_ext}'
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

what I want to do is keep their order, e.g. the first image in the folder starts with "Box - #1.png" and the next one "Box - #2.png", "Box - #3.png", etc. By renaming them I want that to be 0.png, 1.png, 2.png without losing the image that previously was there. When I run the script that order is randomized what was on the image Box - #3.png is not anymore on 2.png and etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `f_name = "" + str(count)`? You can just do `new_name = f'{count}{f_ext}'`

Comment: `enumerate(sorted(os.listdir()))` if you want things sorted as strings, though that won't work the way you want if your numbers aren't zero-padded.

Comment: Explain what you mean by 'randomizes'

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you would need a special key function that compares file names in the same way as the OS.

Comment: ...really, the reliable thing to do would be to parse the numbers out of your filenames .

Comment: @MarkRansom, I'm 90% sure here the OP is assuming that the way bash sorts globs by `LC_COLLATE` order is magically what "the filesystem" does, when it's really shell behavior. `sorted()` on strings should come up pretty much identical to collation order.

Comment: (there _are_ filesystems that impose their own sort order on directories -- typically the same ones that provide indexed lookup for O(1) access to individual files in huge directories -- but it's behavior that varies between individual filesystems so one can't write portable software that depends on it; and that native tree iteration order may or may not look like sort order, depending on implementation details).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hard to say, the OP never specifies an OS.  But I think the key is to recognize that `os.listdir()` doesn't return files in any specific order.  That's where the randomization happens.

Comment: @MarkRansom, ...right, meaning that it's the underlying filesystem's native order, which as I discuss above is implementation-defined. However, the OP is pretty clearly telling us what they _expect_, which involves having a file containing `#1` sort with `#2`. I don't know if they also expect `#10` to sort before `#2`, but that's what would happen in typical practice (doing a character-by-character sort on collation order).

Comment: @JCaesar Meaning what was on image "Box - 1.png" is no longer the same image after the renaming the files its another image that was previously name Box - 223.png

Comment: A/ Are you sure that there will never be a gap in the names enumeration: if there is one, any algorithm not based on the numeric part of the names will be flawed. B/ I would go the safe way: 1: extract the numeric part of the name, 2: substract 1 (as it seems requested but I wonder why) 3: rename

Comment: @hpchavaz, the place I worry about that algorithm is that the "subtract one" part makes it unstable. Run it twice and you won't have the same output both times, as it'll be trying to transform `0` to `-1`; then if your code isn't robust enough to recognize negative numbers you can have the `-1.png` have its numeric portion matched as `1` and thus transformed to `0` by the _next_ run and you have two files claiming the same name, thus risk of one overwriting the other.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : True, when dealing with files, I am paranoid and always check everything I can before commiting, In this case I would test the presence of `'Box - #'` on all the file names files before renaming. Similarly, I would put a test before your algorithm (imposed order) to  check that all the file names are continuous before any renaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important concept to convey here is that your images *aren't actually in any order in the first place*.

Tools like the shell (when evaluating `*.png` into a list of matching names) will *impose* an order by sorting in the current locale's character collation order, but that order isn't reliably enforced at the filesystem layer; and `os.listdir()` is just passing through what the filesystem layer returns without modifying it at all.

You can impose your own order by passing content through `sorted()` before it gets to `enumerate()`:

```
for count, f in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir())):
```

...or, better, you can create a key by extracting the number and parsing it *as a number* (which will ensure that your code understands that `10` is greater than `2`, whereas a character-by-character comparison makes `2` sort after `10`):

```
import re

numberKey_re = re.compile(r'[#](\d+)')
def numberKey(filename):
    match = numberKey_re.search(filename)
    if match is None:
      return (None, filename)
    else:
      return (int(match.groups(1)), filename)

for count, f in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(), key=numberKey)):
```